# ADF data flow how to handle empty string when converting to integer

Tags: azure-data-factory

How does one handle the conversion of string to integer when copying data from one sql table to another using ADF data flow?
I have one field that is empty and using the toInteger() function is causing an error.
how can I tell the expression to not convert if the value is null?

I see there is an if expression but i am unsure how to get it to work correctly. I tried using the iif, but the copy still fails as the toInteger() function cannot convert an empty string to integer

`iif(DivisionNumber == ' ',0, toInteger(DivisionNumber))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An empty string is `''` and is different from `' '`. Have you tried without space between your quotes ?

Hope it helps.

Comment: I did try both ways, but got the same message that " Column 'DivisionNumber' contains an invalid value '' "

Comment: have you tried both cases ? Maybe you got `''` `' '` `'   '` `'    '`... In that case, you should try to TRIM() you input like : `iif(trim(DivisionNumber) == ' ',0, toInteger(DivisionNumber))`

Comment: thanks for the solution, after solving my own mistakes with dataflow, this solution worked as well, I marked your solution as the answer to my question as I don't have to cater for all scenarios as AM07300222 recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

Seems we may have many situations here, in this case to use `case()` function may be a better choice, have a try like below:

```
case(DivisionNumber == ' ',0,DivisionNumber == '',0,isNull(DivisionNumber),0,toInteger(DivisionNumber))
```

The value will be replaced by 0 while including these: `' '` or `''` or `null`， Other than this will use `toInteger()`.

If having any other cases need to be transformed you can also add it into this script.

Comment: I tried this as well, but it doesn't seem to help, so now thinking maybe I should rather spend my time figuring out why the copy from json to the sql table didnt insert a null when a value in the json was an empty string.

Comment: So It was be being silly, and once i got my data flow to work correctly, this solution worked as well, so thank you @AM07300222